# restify regular expression on named parameter

Tags: restify

I am using the restify 2.8.4.

Understood that named parameter with regular expression is not supported in 
[Mixing regex and :params in route #247](https://github.com/restify/node-restify/issues/247)

Instead of cobble both logics into one block.

```
server.get ('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  var id = req.params.id; 
  // check with isNaN()
  // if string do this
  // if number do that
}
```

I prefer below code structure:

```
//hit this route when named param is a number
server.get (/user\/:id(\\d+)/, function (req, res, next) {
  var id = req.params.id; 
  // do stuff with id
}

//hit this route when named param is a string
server.get (/user\/:name[A-Za-z]+/, function (req, res, next) {
  var name = req.params.name; 
  // do stuff with name
}
```

Is there a way I can split them into two separate concerns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have mostly already done it yourself. Just remove the identifiers from your route and make sure you use regex capture groups.

```
//hit this route when named param is a number
server.get (/user\/(\d+)/, function (req, res, next) {
    var id = req.params[0]; 
    // do stuff with id
}

//hit this route when named param is a string
    server.get (/user\/([A-Za-z]+)/, function (req, res, next) {
    var name = req.params[0]; 
    // do stuff with name
}
```

Answer edited to incorporate Cheng Ping Onn's input.

Comment: Escaped the second /, pretty much works as advertised.  Thanks @HeadCode