# how can I use a wildcard in restify routes

Tags: regex, wildcard, restify

Being used to express i would write server.get('/*', controller);

However i cannot write '/*' in Restify without getting a error, could someone please help me out here?

A regex expression that could replace the wildcard (server.get(regex, controller)) would be great.

Error:
{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"/fdsfsd does not exist"}

Edit:

This is what I have so far: [a-zA-Z0-9$-/:-?{-~!"^_`@#\ \   \[]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
server.get(/.*/, controller);
```

Restify is expecting a full-fledged regular expression and not just a wildcard.

You might also be interested in how to [capture parameters with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378419/restify-regular-expression-on-named-parameter/32379942#32379942).

Comment: @sciencefyll I removed the quotation marks from around the regular expression. They should have never been there.